# Somebody trying to access my index.php file on ubuntu apache2 server (Laravel)

Tags: apache2, security, hacking, .htaccess, laravel

One of my project someone trying to access my index.php file in laravel.

Logs:-

```json
{ 
   "ip":"45.155.205.108","url":"/index.php?s=/Index/\\think\\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21",
   "agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
}
```

```json
{
  "ip":"45.155.205.108","url":"/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm",
  "agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
}
```

```json
{
  "ip":"54.81.156.74","url":"/",
  "agent":"python-requests/2.24.0"
}
```

anyone, please advise what security configuration needs to add on apache and .htaccess

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do anything. It depends on whether your site is vulnerable to such requests. A typical website could get thousands of such requests - it's not necessarily possible (or at least _maintainable_) to block them. Does your site use a query string at all? Is your site supposed to be accessible to anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I got a solution. I have added following config in my virtual host

```bsh
<Directory /var/www/example.com/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    deny from all
    allow from ***.***.***.***  ----> your ip here
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Ah, so the website/app is not intended to be public and only accessible from your IP address? (You should have stated this in your question.) However, you've mixed old (Apache 2.2) and new (Apache 2.4) mod_auth... directives - the old will take priority here. You've also enabled MultiViews which is probably undesirable with Laravel.